# How to get a parent widget of a simple class which represents image

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I have an image of a ball which is created using a Ball class:

```
class Ball {

public:
    Ball();
    ~Ball();

  public:
    QRect get_rect();
    QImage & get_image();

  private:
    QImage image;
    QRect rect;
    QWidget * m_parent;
    Ping * ping;
        };

Ball::Ball()
{
    image.load("ball.png");
    rect=image.rect();
    reset_state();

    xdir=1;
    ydir=-1;


}
```

Then I have a QWidget class

```
class Ping : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
Ping(QWidget * parent=0);
private:
 Ball * ball;
}

Ping::Ping(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

    ball=new Ball();
}
```

I need a ball to know about the current size of the window, so therefore I need a ball to get a pointer to its parent (a Ping object) and use height() and width() methods. Are there any ways to accomplish it?

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the Ball() constructor.I question the need for having the Ball know about widgets though.

Comment: Thanks. But there seems to be a problem with my code: `Ball(QWidget * parent)` , in ping.cpp: `ball=new Ball(this)`. Shuts down...

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld, It happens when later in ball.cpp i try to use parent->width()...